# How to efficiently search in the following json dict in python and store into list or another dict?

Tags: python

Assuming I have the following JSON Object:

```
{
  "type": "Bands",
  "Artists": [{
    "profile": {
      "name":"Marissa"
      "age": "7"
      "hobbies": [{
        "name":"Skiing",
        "experience": "1 year"
      }]
    },
    "popularsong":{
      "name":"Wishing on a Star"
      "year": 2007
    }
  },
{
    "profile": {
      "name":"Kelsey"
      "age": "7"
      "hobbies": [{
        "name":"Piano",
        "experience": "1 year"
      }]
    }
    "popularsong":{
      "name":"The Twinkle"
      "year": 2007
    }
  },...
  ]
}
```

Assuming this json is loaded into a dictionary with `json.loads(json_string)` 
What is the most efficient means of searching for all "Artist" entries with "age" of "7" and sticking them into an array or another dictionary?

Note that an artist entry is comprised of both the "profile" and the "popular song" something like:

{
        "profile": {
          "name":"Marissa"
          "age": "7"
          "hobbies": [{
            "name":"Skiing",
            "experience": "1 year"
          },
        "popularsong":{
          "name":"The Twinkle"
          "year": 2007
        }

Comment: It's helpful to provide some legal JSON to prototype with. And seconding msw's comment.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[artist for artist in myJson['Artists'] if artist['profile']['age'] == 7]` might work, if I'm mentally parsing that JSON correctly.

Comment: Yes, a list comprehension seems like the way to go. Though in Python it's `if` not `where`, and I think the clause would be `if artist['profile']['age'] == '7'` for the object the OP has given.